# Burger menu doesn't disappear after clicking JS

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a burger menu for the responsiv. I use a classic JS function onclick to show the responsive burger menu . It's work but when I click on the menu, the menu doesn't disappear.

```js
function myFunction() {

  const button = document.getElementById("menuBurgerFunction");
  const y = document.getElementById("SecondNav");
  button.classList.toggle("change");
  if (y.style.display === "") {
    y.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    y.style.display = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="boutonBurger">
  <div class="burger" id="menuBurgerFunction" onclick="myFunction(event)">
    <div class="bar1"></div>
    <div class="bar2"></div>
    <div class="bar3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>


<nav id="SecondNav">
  <ul id="TargetNav">
    <li><a href="#itineraires">Itinéraires</a></li>
    <li><a href="#infoTrafic">Infos trafic</a></li>
    <li><a href="#actualite">Actualité</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Do I need to use event or listener? Maybe there is an easiest way? 
Thx

Comment: Maybe you mean `y.style.display = "none"`? If you're able to use jQuery there's a handy [`toggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function for this.

Comment: `y.style.display = "none";` (salut compatriote)

Comment: There's no need to use jQuery if you're just using a simple toggle functionality, you're doing the right step using toggle method on `classList`

Comment: Hello! I don't want to use jQuery. Display ="none" doesn't work because that why I put empty"". that's disrupt my burger animation in this case.

Comment: You want to hide the menu, but you don't want to use `display: none`? That's a problem. How are you going to hide the menu when you don't want to hide the menu?

Answer (score 0):

Is there an easier way than changing the `display` style of the menu in an if-else block?

Yes, there's a slightly easier way: create a `hidden` class and toggle it on the menu.

CSS:

```css
.hidden {
  display: none'
}
```

JavaScript:

```js
const y = document.getElementById("SecondNav");
y.classList.toggle('hidden');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added show and hide classes and toggling it using those classes. Yes we can make use of the attributes as well

```js
function myFunction(e) {
  const button = document.getElementById("menuBurgerFunction");
  const y = document.getElementById("SecondNav");
  button.classList.toggle("change");
  if (y.classList.contains('show')) {
    y.classList.remove('show');
    y.classList.add('hide');
  } else {
    y.classList.remove('hide');
    y.classList.add('show');
  }
}
```

```css
.show {
  display: block;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="boutonBurger">
  <div class="burger" id="menuBurgerFunction" onclick="myFunction(event)">
    <div class="bar1">icon</div>
    <div class="bar2"></div>
    <div class="bar3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>


<nav id="SecondNav" class="show">
  <ul id="TargetNav">
    <li><a href="#itineraires">Itinéraires</a></li>
    <li><a href="#infoTrafic">Infos trafic</a></li>
    <li><a href="#actualite">Actualité</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, if I give another class to the burger menu, that's disrupt the onclick function and the secondNav never appear. My HTML/CSS and the function are good, I think I just need another function. This one should do if burger menu is show && if the menubar changed
onclick()navbar style.display="none";